# Windows service fails to start

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services

I'm trying to get my head around WCF applications hosted as a Windows service but I'm not sure what's happening here.

Basically, to get started, I've got a literal copy and paste of the code in this article: (I know, I shouldn't)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms733069%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

The service builds fine and I can install it without issue. It shows up in services.msc also. I'm installing it as follows: (from the visual studio command prompt)

```
installutil Service.exe
```

However when it runs, I get the following error:

*The WCFWindowsServiceSample service on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs.*

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First thing to do is to check the application log in the event viewer to see if any errors were recorded there.

Comment: Found an exception in the log:
Service cannot be started. System.InvalidOperationException: Service 'Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.CalculatorService' has zero application (non-infrastructure) endpoints. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no service element matching the service name could be found in the configuration file, or because no endpoints were defined in the service element.

Comment: Did you add the config from the sample?

Comment: Yes, it's an exactly copy from the MSDN page. I overwrote the file again just to make sure but I still have the same problem.

Comment: Are you sure all your types are defined in the Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples namespace?

Comment: It's an exact copy and paste from the article.